# Java 8: Filter list inside object with another list

Tags: java, list, loops, java-stream

I have a list named "foodList" which contains elements of type "Food". The object Food contains a List named "categories" of type "Category".

I am currently implementing a search algorithm to filter food by excluding certain categories.

Excluded Categories are stored inside a List named "excludedCategories".

How can I, using Java 8 and streams, filter the foodList by excluding Food objects whose categoryLists contain any element of the excludedCategories list?

Sample code with loops:

```
for (Food f: foodList)
{
     for (Category c: f.categories)
     {
          if (excludedCategories.contains(c))
          {
               // REMOVE ITEM FROM foodList
          }
     }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Streams are not designed to modify collections. What end result are you looking for?

Comment: What would a Category class look like?  It seems to me that would best be served by an `enum` and using an `EnumSet`  instead of a `List<Category>`.

Comment: A list of food objects containing only food objects whose categories are not inside the excludedCategories List

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Streams shouldn't be used to modify the `List`. Instead you should return a new `List` with only the appropriate elements in it. You could simply flip the logic a little and use filter:

```
foodList.stream().flatMap(e -> e.categories.stream())
                 .filter(c -> !excludedCategories.contains(c))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However it would be much simpler to use the built in methods:

```
foodList.removeIf(e -> !Collections.disjoint(e.categories, excludedCategories));
```

---

[`Collections::disjoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection))

[`Collections::removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

Comment: Your first approach will only contain `categories` as a list I believe. Not the filtered `Food` list

Comment: @SunilDabburi  You are correct!  It will return a `List<Category>` , not a `List<Food>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `stream` to `filter` the `excluded` categories as following

```
foodList.stream()
        .filter(f -> f.categories.stream().noneMatch(c -> excludedCategories.contains(c)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
    foodList.stream().filter(f -> {
        f.setCats(f.getCats().stream().filter(c -> (!excludedCategories.contains(c))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return true;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What is `getCats`?

Comment: getCategories  is getter method for fecthing category list.

Answer (score 0):

```
foodList.removeIf(f -> f.getCategories().stream().anyMatch(excludeCategories::contains));
```

you can use removeIf and anyMatch to achieve the desired result